# Javascript instantiate user-defined class object from given object does not set all properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have a user-defined class `PaymentCoordinator` in javascript with a constructor looking as shown below:

```
constructor(
private amount: number,
private description: string,
private title: string,
private transactionType: string,
private creditors: Array<any>,
private categories: Array<string>,
private startdate: Date = undefined,
private enddate: Date = undefined,
obj: any = false)
```

The last property in the constructor `obj` is used to instantiate a `PaymentCoordinator` object from a given object `obj` - which is like *clone the given object*. In the constructor, if a `obj` is given (`obj !== false`) i do the cloning as follows:

```
obj && Object.assign(this, obj);
```

All properties of the given `obj` are set corretly - except for the one property `categories` which is a array of strings.

I also tried:

```
obj && Object.assign(this, obj);
this.categories = obj.categories
```

But this does also not set the `categories` property on the new created object.

If i plot the `obj.categories` i verified that the array contains strings.

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Can you create reproducible example of this problem, in, let's say Typescript Playground and share it here?

Comment: I believe that you override this variable later by accident. Are you aware that objects (arrays includes) are passed by reference?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski can you please describe me more in detail what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects in JavaScript are passed by reference

```js
const obj = { array: [1, 2, 3] }
const clone = Object.assign({}, obj)
console.log(clone.array)
obj.array.length = 0
console.log(clone.array)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I apply the assign in the same way as you (line 2). Other properties are set correctly - also array type properties (like `creditors`). I don't understand why it is working for some properties and for other properties of the same type not.

Comment: I believe that it works fine but you then clear the array by accident

Comment: A okay now I understand. No I have verified that the array is not cleared by accident. I verified it by checking it directly after the `Object.assign` line. But the array is empty

Comment: you were right, i overwrote the array in another line but the command line output was delayed and returned the overwritten content. Thanks for clarification